# '@android:id' notation in layout files

Tags: android, view, tags

I couldn't find any extensive documentation on the following notation:

```
@android:id/tabs
```

I found the following explanation:

> @android notation is used when referencing resources defined by the
>   Android system

in [this](http://android-wtf.com/2012/11/difference-between-at-plus-id-and-at-id-in-android/) blog.

What does "resources defined by the Android system" mean? Under what circumstances would I use these resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means an id defined by Android as part of the framework, as opposed to an id you create.  You generally use one when you're interacting with a framework component that assumes a certain id will be used, such as ListActivity or ArrayAdapter.